# Extract subarray that share same values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking for some help in relation to the next code:

```
var items = [
  { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
  { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
  { name: 'And', value: 45 },
  { name: 'The', value: -12 },
  { name: 'Magnetic', value: 37 },
  { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
];

// Sort by value
items.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
});
```

So, after I sort the `items` of the array in ascending or descending order, I want to extract the sub-array of objects that share the same value. Is there an easy approach for this in `javascript`?

The output related to previous example should be like:

```
[
  { name: 'Magnetic', value: 37 },
  { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
  { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the array of items sorted by `value` is good because you can take advantage of that and use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to check if the previous item or the next one share the same value with the current inspected item on each iteration:

```js
var items = [
  {name: 'Edward', value: 21},
  {name: 'Sharpe', value: 37},
  {name: 'And', value: 45},
  {name: 'The', value: -12},
  {name: 'Magnetic', value: 37},
  {name: 'Zeros', value: 37},
  {name: 'foo', value: 21}
];

// Sort by value.

items.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

console.log("Sorted items:", items);

// Filter elements that share same value.

let onlyDups = items.filter((o, i, arr) =>
{
    return (i - 1 >= 0 && (arr[i - 1].value === o.value)) ||
           (i + 1 < arr.length && arr[i + 1].value === o.value);
});

console.log("Items that share value:", onlyDups);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Very helpful, Thank you! :)

Comment: @Sandhya3478 Glad to help! Remember you can accept one of the answers if they helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
items.filter((i)=>{
    let duplicate = items.filter((x)=> {
        return x.value === i.value;
    })
    // Return if has duplicate
    return duplicate.length > 1
})
```

output:

```
[{ name: 'Magnetic', value: 37 },  { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 }, { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }]
```